# RedirectToRouteResult Including Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
I want to extend the HandleErrorAttribute so I can redirect to an appropriate error page. I had a look at the implementation of HandleErrorAttribute and noticed that essentially it just returns a ViewResult, that points to a view, that can be defined per Exception type.

I'd like to use the same system as HandleErrorAttribute, except:

1. I'd like to define a Controller for Error pages
2. I want to maintain the Exception as model (HandleErrorInfo)

I could obviously use a RedirectToRouteResult, but I can't pass through the Exception as model, since it's an actual Response.Redirect. And I'd like to avoid having to cache the model server side.

For now I'm just overwriting the ViewResult and manually setting controller. But that still just returns the view and doesn't actually execute the controller.

```
public class ErrorViewResult : ViewResult
{
    public ControllerBase Controller { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    protected override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.Controller = Controller;
        context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = ControllerName;
        return base.FindView(context);
    }
}
```

I have to somehow return a result, that restarts the whole pipeline starting with the Controller.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with TempData functionality, it will store your values only till the next request, and if in between these requests you will do any others or if you use mvc to handle client resources (like dynamically combined css and js files) then you will loose your data.
If you want to start controller manually (with all nested actions) then look at that:

```
   RouteData data = new RouteData();
   data.Values.Add("controller", "error");
   data.Values.Add("action", "Handle500");
   data.Values.Add("area", "");
   data.Values.Add("exception", sb.ToString()); 

   var controller = new MTool.BusinessLogic.Controllers.ErrorController();
   controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext([HttpContextInstance], data, controller);
   controller.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(controller.ControllerContext, "Handle500");
```

Comment: Thanks that is looking promising so far.
But how do I get the result from the InvokeAction(…) into the filterContext.Result?

Comment: OK. got it.
Just have to use
`controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(filterContext.RequestContext, controller);
controller.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(controller.ControllerContext, action);`

Comment: Yeah, this depends on source of invocation. Example from above is situated inside HttpApplication class, so that i can handle both web form and mvc errors in the same way (in case of mixed project).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx)?

`TempData` allows you to store data that can be read on the very next request. If they refresh the page after being redirected it will be gone.

```
TempData["exception"] = exception;
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Now in the get you have access to `TempData["exception"]` for the first GET only, then it is gone. Sounds like what you need.